# Set WKWebView cookie accept policy in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Goal: inject third part cookies into `WKWebView`.

Before iOS 12 I was able to fix the problem through this snippet (see https://medium.com/@flexaddicted/how-to-set-wkwebview-cookie-accept-policy-d8a2d3b77420):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
  guard let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
    let url = navigationResponse.response.url else {
    decisionHandler(.cancel)
    return
  }

  if let headerFields = response.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] {
    let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: url)
    cookies.forEach { cookie in
      webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
    }
  }

  decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Starting from iOS 12 cookies are not available in `WKWebView`'s response.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188691

Do you know any workaround to fix this?

Comment: Have you ever managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @timbru31 nope, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, but it's a bit "hacky".

Create a method that returns URL :

1. Create a `DispatchSemaphore` to send synchronous request
2. Execute request in `URLSession`
3. At the end of DataTask, retrieve response?.url

Before loading content in `WKWebView`, set cookies in `WKWebView` from `URLSession`.

And it works like a charm.

```swift
func getAuthenticatedURL(from url: URL) -> URL? {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:0)

    var result: URL? = nil

    session.dataTask(with: url) { _, response, _ in
        result = response?.url
        semaphore.signal()
    }.resume()

    semaphore.wait()

    return result
}
```

```swift
let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()

let ctrl = WKUserContentController()

conf.userContentController = ctrl

let wkDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()

wkDataStore.removeData(
    ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(),     
    modifiedSince: .distantPast) { }

HTTPCookieStorage.shared
                .cookies?
                .forEach { wkDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie($0) }

conf.websiteDataStore = wkDataStore

wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: conf)

// ...

// Get URL from getAuthenticatedURL and load in wkWebView
```